Data Cloud Admin Permission Set Not Working with Marketing User Profile
My client is a bank so they're pretty strict on security. I have assigned a user the Marketing User profile and added the Data Cloud Admin permission set.
When I pull up a Unified Profile (Profile Explorer > search for records > Click "View" link on record), no data loads. It works fine when I switch this user's profile to System Administrator (which does not meet my client's security requirements). I have cloned the Marketing User profile and added every Data Cloud permission I could find. It still doesn't work.
What is the permission on a profile that will allow access to all Data Cloud functionality? I noticed that the object the Profile Explorer pulls up is UnifiedssotIndividualCon__dlm but I can't find this object in the list of object permissions on the profile.

Have you granted access to the default data space for that user? You might need to create a new permission set with a data cloud license to add the data space.
